# different ssh login methods

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, private-key, public-key

Could you please help me to understand bellow authentication methods

1. `ssh -i PrivateKey.pem ec2-user@52.48.32.12`
2. Password less athentication

As per the my understanding in both above cases we use private key and public key. In both methods pubic keys are stored in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in the server which need to login.

1. In first method user provides corresponding private key. But in second method how authentication mechanism know what is the corresponding private key as user not supply the private key.
2. Can we arrange pass wordless authentication like `ssh -i id_rsa ec2-user@52.48.32.12`
3. Can we use two public keys and two private keys to authenticate to the same server from same client.

Answer (score 1):

> In first method user provides corresponding private key. But in second method how authentication mechanism know what is the corresponding private key as user not supply the private key.

The client is using private keys in default location (`~/.ssh/id_{rsa,dsa,ecdsa,ed25519}`).

> Can we arrange pass wordless authentication like ssh -i id_rsa ec2-user@52.48.32.12

Yes, the filename does not matter. But of course it has to be a valid private key.

> Can we use two public keys and two private keys to authenticate to the same server from same client.

Yes. But servers are usually fine with accepting single key, so there is no need to do that.

Comment: It is like this.
Suppose we can log into servers using the private keys provided company's IT  team.After logged into those servers we need to configure ssh authentication between those servers.But we can not store individual user's private keys inside each servers...
Can we do that ?

Comment: You can use `ssh-agent` and it's forwarding capability to authenticate users with their local keys on the further jumps.

Comment: Can you also tell me ,Is there a way to tell sshd to first match the public key in the entries in authorized_keys file and then match with ldap server

Comment: @UtpMahesh afaik, it does that, if you specify `AuthorizedKeysCommand` to fetch your keys from ldap.

Comment: can you please share the command.firt need to check in ~/i.ssh/authorized_keys and then ldap server.
This is current configs of my ssh server
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/openssh-ldap-publickey
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

Comment: You are asking different questions. This is not a discussion forum, but Q&A and your original question was already answered (therefore there is the tick on the left to accept it). If you have a new question, there is a button on the top right you can follow.